# Can't make my first spider run,any advice?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my first time using scrapy and maybe the third in python, so i'm a noob.
The problem with this code is that it doesn't even enter the page.

I have tried to use:
scrapy shell 'https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico'

This works and then using...

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="product__varianttitle ui-text--small"]')
```

... I can retrieve information.

#### My code:

```py
import scrapy

class ZooplusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Zooplus'
    allowed_domains = ['zooplus.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico']

def parse(self, response):
    item= scrapy.Item() 
    item['nombre']=response.xpath('//*[@class="product__varianttitle ui-text--small"]')             
    item['preciooriginal']=response.xpath('//*[@class="product__prices_col prices"]')
    item['preciorebaja']=response.xpath('//*[@class="product__specialprice__text"]')
    return item
```

#### The error message says:

```
2019-08-30 21:16:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-30 21:16:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-30 21:16:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-08-30 21:16:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zooplus.es/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-08-30 21:16:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico> from <GET https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico/>
2019-08-30 21:16:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico> (referer: None)
2019-08-30 21:16:58 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.zooplus.es/shop/tienda_perros/pienso_perros/pienso_hipoalergenico> (referer: None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't defined the fields for your items.py
the error is coming from **item['nombre']**

Either you should define the field in items.py or simply replace
<strike>item= scrapy.Item()</strike>
with `item = dict()`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Madhav I have tried it and the problem is not solved. It sure was an error defining the object but there is another one which doesnt even let the spider to crawl in the web.

Comment: @SSD93 you should add the new error to your question because otherwise nobody can help resolve it. The answer did fix the problem your posted.